# Is it good practice to store client_id and client_secret on a flutter mobile application needed for Github OAuth Login?

Tags: flutter, api, github, oauth

I'm developing a Flutter application along with an API that will serve data to the app. For my login, I've gone with the [Github's OAuth Apps](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/oauth-apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps).

The flow that I follow is:

1. Launch [Chrome custom tabs](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_tabs) for user to sign in.
2. Wait for the GitHub to redirect using [Deep Links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links)
3. Upon getting auth code, make a `POST` request to GitHub's API with

   - `client_id`
   - `client_secret`
   - `auth_code`
     as it's said per [GitHub's documentation here](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/oauth-apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps#2-users-are-redirected-back-to-your-site-by-github) to retrieve a user token.

My question is, is it good practice to store `client_id` and `client_secret` in my Flutter app? Or should I migrate the PCKE logic to my API, thus the app doesn't have any client_id client_secret stored and just makes a request with the auth_code to my API and awaits a token in return?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is the access token valid indefinitely (until revoked, and new login needed)?

If so, it sounds like this is a very rarely occuring process, which would mean little to no use of the stored **client_id** and **client_secret**. Consequently, even if you safely could, there's no reason to do it. And it might even save you some implementation time to keep it simple and local.

Comment: Yes! the access token is valid until revoked, or the user signs out. So if I understand you correct, you're suggesting the client_id, client_secret should be in my API, therefore the PCKE steps should be implemented in the backend rather than the app?